# Can you suggest any good word, phrase, quote of the day resources?

Tags: online-resource

Can you suggest any blogs, email subscriptions, twitter feeds etc. of German words, phrases, or quotes of the day?

I'm looking for something that will present me daily with a single random word/phrase/quote. It could be an email or a twitter feed (or some similar asynchronous presentation). For example, in English there's a site called [A Word A Day](https://wordsmith.org/words/today.html). You can visit to get a word, or you can subscribe to get an email of that word. I'm looking for something similar but for German.

If you can please give links and your assessment of the words/phrases.

Any and all kinds are welcome. Famous quotes from authors, vocabulary for school children, slang expressions, whatever.

Any medium is OK. Twitter feed, email, whatever (even paper mail, but online is best).

*(any suggestions on refining this question to make it reopenable are welcome)*

Comment: https://www.aphorismen.de/ or https://de.wikiquote.org/wiki/Hauptseite - and I assume your question will be closed. Because it is very broad and I don't see where you struggle in German grammar/ typo/ understanding beside ... using a search engine with "Zitat des Tages" or similiar.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm I surely have attempted all variations of 'wort des tages' or other, but since my German is not very good, I don't know if I'm using the right keywords. But both those sites look great for quotes - do they have a way to subscribe to get daily emails? (or you could add an answer!)

Comment: so then please try to include some of your research. Just to narrow down a bit where you struggled. I know that it is de facto impossible to look for an unknown word. I actually did only suggest the search term, not trying it out.

Comment: This question is probably too open-ended, but a good resource for in-depth explanations of particularly tricky words and phrases (in English by a German-speaking author): [yourdailygerman.com](http://yourdailygerman.com)

Comment: I don't understand why people are so averse to questions asking for resources.

Comment: Can  anyone give advice on how (or whether) to make this reopenable?  @ShegitBrahm xish, closers?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think specifying more precisely what you're trying to gain from these resources that couldn't be gained from standard resources (dictionary, grammar reference, etc.), because as the question is, it's unclear how anyone could give a meaningful answer that differs from a Google search.

Comment: @xish Edited to hopefully clarify, with an English example. I'd prefer an email or twitter field to have it presented to me within other situations rather than having to go visit that particular site explicitly.

Comment: @Mitch: Can you describe what you are _not_ looking for? I mean, "twitter feeds of German words..." that is like following dudes writing on twitter in German, popular ones quite often. I just doubt that this is what you look for. I guess you not only want a word a day but also the explanation for it?

Comment: Does the email need to contain anything besides the word/phrase itself? (The definition, translation, etc.) Is it a requirement that it be curated by a human (i.e., not generated by a script/bot)?

Comment: The reason I ask is that it might be relatively easy to use a service like [visualping](https://visualping.io/) or [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/) to set something up, but it depends somewhat on what your minimum requirements are.

Comment: @xish I'm just wondering what the good sources for German content is. I'd prefer email or twitter (easiest with least intervention). The only online German dictionary I use is dict.leo, but it doesn't have a WotD that the commercial English dictionaries tend to (like Merriam-Webster). If there online German dictionaries have a WotD subscription service, then great, that would make a good answer here.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check the online version of Duden (a dictionary of the German language). They have a "Word of the Day" section:  https://www.duden.de/wort-des-tages

Comment: If you find it useful, you could enhance your answer that Duden-Verlag says on this page, that the Word of the day is available via Twitter - as the OP likes. Even if that functionality depends on site owner, it is favored to include the relevant website content into an answer. (and maybe also Amazon Skill)